# juniper VPN disconnect when I use SCP

Tags: vpn, scp, juniper

I am using Juniper in my company. I have a 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 laptop.
I can ssh to remote servers, and do everything well.
My problem is : whenever I scp something to the remote server, Juniper disconnect me from the VPN so that I am disconnected from the servers.
Do anyone has that problem before ?  Can you help me fix it.
Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread so probably no use to the OP, however, we had a similar problem caused by the private IP address range on each end of the VPN being the same. In our case the client was in the 192.168.1.0/24 range. The client would be fine connecting to hosts in most network ranges, but any request to a server in our DMZ on 192.168.1.0/24 would cause issues. Changing the home router range to another (we suggested 192.168.0.0/24) solved the issue. This was using Checkpoint VPN not Juniper, but the symptoms seem similar.